# How can I find element(his index) with class added by jquery function addClass()?

Tags: jquery, indexing, addclass

I have this "on click" function that should find out position(index) of element with class "on". In my HTML I wrote this class to the first child. Everything works good when I first execute function, but after the class is added to another sibling and removed from the first child, element with class .on cannot be found. thx for answers

```
 $( "body" ).on("click",".arrow" ,function() {
      var position = $(this).parent().children().index(".on") + 1; 
      alert(position);
      var new_position = count_position(direction, position, img_num); 
      $(this).addClass("off").removeClass("on");
      $(this).addClass("on").removeClass("off");
  });
```

Comment: Can you provide more code?

Comment: why are you adding the class 'off' and removing it in the next line? and why are you removing the class 'on' and adding it in the next line?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886571/function-doesnt-identify-class-after-switching-it-with-other-sibling-using-addcl